# undefined method `update' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

models associations are as below:

Model I

```
class TimeLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :custom_time_field,  :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Model II

```
class CustomTimeField <  ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :time_log
end
```

Error details:

```
a = TimeLog.find(1)
a.custom_time_field

#returns => #<CustomTimeField id: 1, time_entry_id: 1, status: 'incomplete', start_time: "2000-01-01 11:24:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 11:24:00">

a.custom_time_field.update(1, :status => '') # returns undefined method `update'
```

However a.custom_time_field.update_attributes() works

Now i can use update_attributes also i can use save method by creating object

But Why cant i use update method in such case? this is useful when multiple attributes need to updated at a time.

Comments/Pointers?

Comment: i realized that update method works on class and not on object. but then how can i call it using class with have one association?

Comment: Some confusion is there: does your CustomTimeFields class need 's' at the end? Log shows it's named without 's'.

Comment: oh yes. thnx for bringing into notice.

Comment: `has_one :custom_time_fields` also needs to be changed ;)

Comment: i am doing a lot of typos today.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` is a class method of your model. Call it this way:

```
CustomTimeField.update(1, :status => '')
```

Comment: i wish i could use this. but i have id for TimeLog at run time. thnx for hints though

Comment: I just told that `update` is used when you know the id. When you already have an instance of your model, then `record.update_attributes` is perfectly suitable.